# CQRS in the java world

Tags: java, .net, cqrs

I follow the discussion about cqrs a long time now.

Something that occured to me, is that the programming language of choice is mostly settled in the dot.Net world.

Is there any reasons why this is the case? Why dind't the concepts of cqrs nest themself in the java world yet? Is there a another concept/architecture style, maybe different named in the java strathosphere i don't know yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terms of CQRS and DDDD originated in .NET world and were pushed by .NET Practitioners like Greg Young and Udi Dahan.

Less people are talking about CQRS in Java world. However, since the [CQRS term](http://abdullin.com/cqrs/) itself is just mostly a new name for time-proven practices (united under a simple mental model), it is not limited to .NET only.

For example, there are [Axon](http://www.axonframework.org/) and [Jdon](http://jdon.sf.net) frameworks in Java. They are frequently referenced in CQRS discussions.

Comment: ok, thanks. It seems that my guessing was right. So maybe it's about time to spread the world wider in the java world. By the way, i really enjoy reading your blog especially this post: http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/9/26/theory-of-cqrs-command-handlers-sagas-ars-and-event-subscrip.html

Comment: FYI, I'm using Axon on the server side for a project, and it's pretty robust.  There are still some rough corners, but nothing too terrible unless you're dealing with some edge cases in the CQRS universe.

Answer (score -1):

CQRS is far from dead in the java world.  spring framework will debut spring 4 
in September or October 2013, it will feature the axon framework...
spring already uses some event based framework

asp.net seems to use workflow with the cloud based azure or
pigg cms asp.net mvc Multilanguage cqrs

Personally I stick with Java however I wanted to be fair to .net
Touchscreen technology needs a command or event based framework 
with .net or java!!!